# Choose the correct statement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be any $m \times n$ matrix of rank $n$ with real entries. Then choose the correct statement-

1. $Ax=b$ has a solution for any $b$.
2. $Ax=0$ does not have a solution.
3. If $Ax=b$ has a solution, then it is unique.
4. $y^tA=0$ for some non-zero $y$.

Rank=$n$ means $n \le m$, and option 2, is clearly false as $0$ is a solution.
My guess is 3, as  it has a solution iff $A$ is invertible, correct and then it is unique. I am not sure about fourth.

Answer (score 2):

The rank-nullity theorem implies
$$
\dim\DeclareMathOperator{null}{null}\null(A)+\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank}\rank(A)=n
$$
Since $\rank(A)=n$, it follows that 
$$
\dim\null(A)=0
$$
But this implies that the linear map $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ given by $\vec x\mapsto A\vec x$ is injective. Hence if $A\vec x=\vec b$ has a solution, then the solution is unique.

So option (3) certainly holds. Can you think of counterexamples to the others?